# Java get specific data from dynamic JSONObject

Tags: java, json, dynamic

I have a JSON String and convert it to JSONObject.

I want to get specific data from the JSONObject, and every time the JSONObject changes its structure, sometimes it's in an array inside the JSON and sometimes not.
example:
the first time the JSON arrives like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "Name": "Jack",
  "Value": {
    "data": [
      {"time": "2023", "age": "22"}
    ]
}}
```

the second time

```
{ 
  "age": "22",
  "time": "2023",
  "Value": {
    "data": [
      {"Name": "Jack", "id": "1" }
    ]
}}
```

if I want to get the name in the first JSON

```
jsonObject.getString("Name")
```

and for the second one, I would use

```
jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("Name")
```

is there a way I can get the value dynamically regardless of where the keys are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API come from an another team or an external provider, the first thing I would suggest to you, is to clearly define a contract. Otherwise, you can use the `isNull(String key)` method of `JSONObject` to check if the key exists or not.

An example here:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
String nameValue;

if(jsonObject.isNull("Name")) {
    nameValue = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Value")
                .getJSONArray("data")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("Name");
} else {
    nameValue = jsonObject.getString("Name");
}

System.out.println(nameValue);
```

Comment: thank you this worked for me to check for the values.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON strings are always in a similar fashion then you can try a little parser method as provided below. It returns a Key/Value (String/Object) Map:

```
public static java.util.Map<String, Object> mapJsonObject(String jsonString) {
    String json = jsonString
            .replaceAll("(?i)[\\[\\]\\{\\}\"]|\"?value\"?:|\"?data\"?:|\n?", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    String[] keyValueParts = json.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    java.util.Map<String, Object> map = new java.util.HashMap<>();
    for (String str : keyValueParts) {
        String[] pts = str.split("\\s*:\\s*");
        map.put(pts[0].trim(), pts[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

To use:

```
String jsonString = "{\n"
            + "  \"id\": \"1\",\n"
            + "  \"Name\": \"Jack\",\n"
            + "  \"Value\": {\n"
            + "    \"data\": [\n"
            + "      {\"time\": \"2023\", \"age\": \"22\"}\n"
            + "    ]\n"
            + "}}";

java.util.Map<String, Object> map = mapJsonObject(jsonString);
System.out.println(map);
```

The console window will display:

```
{id=1, time=2023, age=22 , Name=Jack}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson1 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": \"1\"," +
    "  \"Name\": \"Jack\"," +
    "  \"Value\": {" +
    "    \"data\": [" +
    "      {\"time\": \"2023\", \"age\": \"22\"}" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "}");

Josson josson2 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{ " +
    "  \"age\": \"22\"," +
    "  \"time\": \"2023\"," +
    "  \"Value\": {" +
    "    \"data\": [" +
    "      {\"Name\": \"Jack\", \"id\": \"1\" }" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
```

**Query**

`*()` is a multi-level wildcard search. It returns the first resolvable element.

```
System.out.println(josson1.getString("coalesce(Name, *().Name)"));
// Output: Jack

System.out.println(josson2.getString("coalesce(Name, *().Name)"));
// Output: ["Jack"]
// It is because "Name" is inside array "data".

System.out.println(josson1.getString("coalesce(Name, *().Name).first()"));
// Output: Jack

System.out.println(josson2.getString("coalesce(Name, *().Name).first()"));
// Output: Jack
// Added function first() to extract the value.
```

Comment: thank you I did a manual search in different levels, I will give it a try next time.